# problem using boost in c++ app

Tags: c++, c, boost

Once I added the following include to my app:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
```

It spits out some errors I have no idea what they are about (newbie to c++):

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/regex/regex_traits.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex.hpp:39,
                 from /usr/include/boost/regex.hpp:31,
                 from my_app.c:28:
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80:1: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: template declaration of âchar (& boost::re_detail::test)[2]â
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: expected unqualified-id before â...â token
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: expected `)' before â...â token
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: expected `)' before â...â token
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: expected unqualified-id before â(â token
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_traits.hpp:80: error: âboost::re_detail::has_boost_extensions_tag<T, fallback_>::valueâ is not a valid template argument for type âboolâ because it is a non-constant expression
```

I installed boost on centos using:

```
yum install boost boost-devel boost-doc
```

I compile the app using:

```
g++ -o my_app my_app.c $(mysql_config --libs --cflags
```

Headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Any code before the `#include`?

Comment: just a bunch of other headers and some constants, does that matter?

Comment: My guess is one of the other headers is defining a macro `test` that is conflicting with boost.

Comment: I've updated with the headers

Comment: I'd try moving regex up to the top of the inlcude list and see if that fixes it. If it does, then you might try moving it back down one at a time to identify the offending header, then see if you can do anything about its antisocial behaviour.

Comment: By the way, that's an odd mixture of "old-style" standard headers with the .h and "new-style" ones without. That's a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: If you remove the offending `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` it works? ?!?!?

Comment: Found the culprit, it was "#include <my_global.h>", not even sure what that header is or why it was in my app

Answer (score 0):

Is this accidential or are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler?

Try to rename your file to `my_app.cc` or so to see if that helps.

Comment: it was originally written in c, but I had to use g++ to compile it after some other code was added, believe me I have no idea what I"m doing, as long as it compiles I don't care :)